# Viber Call button on responsive mobile website

Tags: wordpress, viber

Does anyone know how to embed a call button for Viber in a responsive website in order to make a call to a specific number, either from desktop or a mobile phone?

I have a Wordpress website and my client asked me to embed a Viber call button to his office.

Answer (score 0):

Use this javascript code for the Whatsapp share button:

```
<a onclick="window.open('whatsapp://send?text=Post or page title + http://www.yoursite.com/post-url/', 'Share on Whatsapp','width=400,height=400,location=no');return false;" href="#" class="large-share-button light wa"><span class="social_text">Whatsapp</span></a>
```